# Доступ к закрытому потоку невозможен

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Использую библиотеку [IronBarCode](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/barcode/object-reference/api/).

```
string input = $"{(char)0x00F1}(01){gtin}(11){dateStart}(17){expirationDate}(10)10(21){partNum}";
GeneratedBarcode barcode = BarcodeWriter.CreateBarcode(input, BarcodeWriterEncoding.Code128).ResizeTo(300, 30);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (Stream stream = barcode.ToWindowsBitmapStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(ms);
    }
    ms.Position = 0;
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        printDialog.PrintVisual(img, "Распечатываем элемент Image");
    });
}
```

В данном коде появляется ошибка "Доступ к закрытому потоку невозможен." на строке  `stream.CopyTo(ms);`.

Comment: Я понял, что за ошибка. Но вполне вероятно, она за пределами показанного кода. И снова вы не пишете, что за библиотеку используете и т.д. Здесь телепатов нет. Вы скопировали этот код из своего проекта или из моего ответа на прошлый ваш вопрос?

Comment: Да, этот код взял из проекта. В следующий раз приму к сведению ваши замечания. Спасибо большое. На сей раз работает все стабильно!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Окей, давайте по-другому сделаем. Согласно [документации](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/barcode/object-reference/api/IronBarCode.GeneratedBarcode.html), можно не поток, а массив получить.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(barcode.ToWindowsBitmapBinaryData()))
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        printDialog.PrintVisual(img, "Распечатываем элемент Image");
    });
}
```

Comment: Получается какая-то странная вещь. Когда я запускаю проект через visual studio в сборке release, то все работает. А в том случае если запускаю через exe Release то принтер не печатает.

Comment: Возможно знаете в чем может быть проблема? Все доступы я дал и запуск приложения идет от имени администратора

Comment: @AlexSuspect возможно какой-то библиотеки не хватает в папке с приложением, не знаю, отлаживайте, ловите исключения.

Comment: отлаживаю приложение через visual studio и все работает стабильно, а после того как запускаю приложение через exe файл через папку release принтер просто не отвечает, но кнопка нажимается

Comment: Возможен ли вылет приложения из-за драйверов? Хотя в редакторе все работает стабильно

Comment: @AlexSuspect Журнал Windows можно посмотреть. Там может быть информация об исключении. А вообще try-catch вам в помощь.

Comment: код обернут в try-catch и никаких ошибок нет. Открыл журнал Windows и увидел там ошибку - 
Имя сбойного модуля: KERNELBASE.dll, версия: 10.0.19041.2130, метка времени: 0x3206f737

Comment: @AlexSuspect я не знаю, что это значит и относится ли вообще к вашему приложению.